Exploring Change Detection Models for Analyzing Product Metrics on Python/R
I'm seeking guidance on categorizing and defining change detection models to analyze metrics such as sales, number of clients, and quantity for product categories. I want to provide an overview of these models for my analysis.
Researching various change detection models.
Attempting to categorize and define the models based on their underlying principles and applications.
Exploring how each model could be applied to detect changes in product metrics.
I expected to have a clear understanding of different change detection models and how they can be used to analyze changes in product metrics. However, I'm struggling to organize and define these models effectively.
